# Starting another program that shares output terminal with current program?

Tags: terminal, background-process, io, matlab

I have a matlab script that I run from the terminal, that script creates an instance of another program using:

```
system('cd <path> && mpiexec -n 1 ./<program2> &')
```

Problem is I don't see any terminal output from `program2`. (It works if I omit the ampersand, but I need `program2` to run in the background). Is it possible to have both the matlab script and `program2` output to the same terminal?

Comment: Hmm, it's not clear at all what MATLAB does if anything with the output from `system('cmd&')`; I suspect you'll need to find a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can add `>&/dev/tty` to the mpiexec command to make it output to the terminal.

Comment: @meuh It didn't work. Still no output in terminal. Output works fine if I direct it to a logfile though... `'....  ./<program2> > logfile 2>&1 &'`